# Como puedo hacer el codigo css en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Con este CSS hago la animacion de los tres Divs, dicha animacion consiste en poner el segundo div encima del primero pasando el primero atras y moviendo el tercer div al segundo puesto y asi ir mostrando todos los divs uno por uno.

```
    .card{
      position: absolute;
      transform: scale(0.75);
      height:200px;
      width:300px;
      animation-name: cards-animation;
      animation-iteration-count:infinite;
      animation-duration: 6s;
    }
    .card-blue{
      background-color:blue;
      animation-delay: 1s;
    } 
    .card-red{
      background-color:red;
      animation-delay: 3s;
    }
    .card-green{
      background-color:green;
      animation-delay: 5s;
    }

    @keyframes cards-animation {
      0%  {
        transform: scale(0.75) ;
        z-index: 0;
      }
      9% {
        transform: scale(0.9) translateY(40px);
        z-index: 2;
      }
      33% {
        transform: scale(0.9) translateY(40px);
        z-index: 2;
      }
      42% {
        transform: translateY(80px);
        z-index: 3;
      } 
      66% {
        transform: translateY(80px);
        z-index: 3;
        opacity: 1;
      }
      75% {
        transform: translateY(130px);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      80% {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateY(40px);
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
      } 
      90% {
        transform: scale(0.75);
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 1;
      }
    }
```

Lo que necesito es saber como puedo pasar el codigo CSS que hace esa animación a un codigo de Javascript, osea tener la misma animación pero en lugar de hacerla con CSS, hacerla con Javascript para poder tener mas control sobre ella.

```
         <div class="card card-blue"></div>
         <div class="card card-red"></div>
         <div class="card card-green"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema de tenerlo con CSS?

Comment: Necesito pasarlo a Javascript porque necesito agregarle unas funciones extra, y puedo manejar mejor lo que pasa en los divs si lo tengo con un codigo de JS.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes poner el CSS con `setAttribute` de un elemento:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('id');

div.setAttribute('style', 'height: 20px; width: 20px; background-color: red');
```

```html
<div id="id"></div>
```

O con `Object.assign`:

```js
const css = {
  'background-color': 'red',
  height: '20px',
  width: '20px',
};
 
const elemento = document.getElementById("id");
Object.assign(elemento.style, css);
```

```html
<div id="id"></div>
```